# Toggle a pane in Tmux

Tags: tmux

During development, I typically have the following panes open:

```
+---------------------------+
|               |           |
|               |           |
|               |   Term1   |
|               |           |
|      Vim      |-----------|
|               |           |
|               |           |
|               |   Term2   |
|               |           |
|               |           |
+---------------------------+
```

I've mapped `<F2>` using the following to open up a small split under `Vim` to show `tig`.

```
bind-key -n F2 split-window -v -t 1 -l 25 -c "#{pane_current_path}" tig status
```

Resulting in this:

```
+---------------------------+
|               |           |
|               |           |
|               |   Term1   |
|      Vim      |           |
|               |-----------|
|               |           |
|---------------|           |
|               |   Term2   |
|      Tig      |           |
|               |           |
+---------------------------+
```

This works great for creating and focusing the pane, but I'd like to be able to press `<F2>` again to close the pane, regardless of if that pane is selected. This will let me press `<F2>` to toggle whether the `Tig` pane is open or not.

The challenges I've faced so far when playing with this are:

- `kill-pane -t "{bottom-left}"` will kill the `Vim` pane if the `Tig` pane isn't present
- `kill-pane -t "{down-of}"` will kill the `Vim` pane if the `Tig` pane is selected (it wraps back to the top)
- I'm not sure how to conditionally run the `kill-pane` or `split-window` based on if the `Tig` pane is currently open.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split-window can show the pane ID so you can save it and use it to kill the pane - IDs are always unique so you will never kill the wrong pane. You'll need a couple of bits of sh, one to open the pane and store the ID in a user option, something like (not tested):

```
bind A run-shell 'P=$(tmux splitw -PF'#{pane_id}' -- mycommand); tmux set -w @myspecialpane "$P"'
```

And one to kill it, something like:

```
bind B run-shell 'P=$(tmux show -wqv @myspecialpane); [ -n "$P" ] && tmux killp -t$P'
```

Actually since you want them to be the same key you will need to be a bit more sophisticated and check if the pane is already there - I would write a little script and call it with run-shell from your key binding, something like this (also not tested):

```
P=$(tmux show -wqv @myspecialpane)
if [ -n "$P" ] && tmux lsp -F'#{pane_id}'|grep -q ^$P; then
     tmux killp -t$P
     tmux set -wu @myspecialpane
else
     P=$(tmux splitw -PF'#{pane_id}' -- mycommand)
     tmux set -w @myspecialpane "$P"
fi
```

Comment: Your shell script worked beautifully. Thank you!